# how to use phrase match in elastic.js?

Tags: elasticsearch

i want to use phrase match in elastic.js. 
the docs says

```
"match": {
    "title": {
        "query": "quick brown fox",
        "type":  "phrase"
    }
}
```

i want to do this

```
ejs.BoolQuery().must(
                    ejs.FilteredQuery(
                        ejs.MatchAllQuery(),
                        ejs.TermsFilter('expressNumber', ['as1243432','sd4324324']).type('phrase')
                    )
                );
```

There is not enough examples.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a `phrase match` you need to use the [`MatchQuery`](http://docs.fullscale.co/elasticjs/ejs.MatchQuery.html), not the `TermsFilter`. In your case, it should go like this:

```
ejs.BoolQuery().must(
    ejs.MatchQuery("expressNumber", "as1243432 sd4324324").type("phrase")
);
```

Comment: i knew matchQuery. But the check data is array.

Comment: Have you tried "joining" the array with a space character, `['as1243432','sd4324324'].join(' ')`?

Comment: {
     "match": {
           "expressNumber": {
                "query": "as1243432 sd4324324",
                "type": "phrase"
              }
          }
    }
seems right but can't get any result

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more about your data and mapping. What makes you think that you need a "match phrase" in the first place?

Comment: sorry for that, i just want to check express numbers without analyzer. the data just like `['DG123343434', 'DH32343', 'da1243243']`. if the data is string, use `ejs.MatchQuery("expressNumber", "as1243432").type("phrase")` will get right result.